# Override contains function in jmespath

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, jmespath

I am trying to override [_func_contains](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py/blob/2ad18b0e51ef3c22ef0d4bbeb11506746a39e228/jmespath/functions.py#L214C20-L214C20) from [jmespath](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py) but the program always execute method from parent class. I don't know what I am missing.

Here is my code snippet

```
from jmespath import functions

class CustomFunctions(functions.Functions):
    @functions.signature({'types': ['array', 'string']}, {'types': []})
    def _func_contains(self, subject, search):
        if search is None:
            return False
        else:
            return search in subject
```